# Querying a specific JSON key value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql (v5.7.23) table contain a json object like this

```
[{
    "plant_part": "Leaves, Seed",
    "extract_type": "Ethanol",
    "activity": "Colon Cancer",
    "reference": "6"
  },
  {
    "plant_part": "Leaves, Seed",
    "extract_type": "Ethanol",
    "activity": "Lung Cancer",
    "reference": "6"
  }]
```

Now i want to get value from only the "activity" key. and this is what I'm trying.

```
$sql = "select * from table where column like '%".$term."%';
```

but this will select all value from that column. Is there any way get result from specific key?

I mean something like this?

```
$sql = "select * from table where column.activity like '%".$term."%';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do not try it in SQL. use a json Parser in php

Comment: Look at MySQL 's json functions

Comment: @Strawberry is this introduced in mysql 5.7?

Comment: @Edwin I'm no more qualified to answer that than you, but a limited set of json functions are available in 5.7 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: @Strawberry before 5.7 I didn't find any reference about it, so I asked because I thought you may know the answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i think you need to ask yourself why you are storing json objects for such a thing rather than a table with the proper columns. i can't think of a good reason to store a json object in one column tbh (doesn't mean there isn't one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) to find the values of `activity` and compare them:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM table
        WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(column,  '$[*].activity') LIKE '%".$term."%'";
```

For your sample data the `JSON_EXTRACT` will return `["Colon Cancer", "Lung Cancer"]` which can then be compared against e.g. `"%Cancer%"`.